# How do you create a .json file on mac?

Tags: json

*newbie here*
Have a set of API keys, my project instructions are to -
"Update keys.local with those keys, then create a json file." - by way of:

```
cp keys.local keys.json
```

Guessed that was a terminal command? Only when I created a TextEdit file called keys.local, tried entering that code into terminal, got this error:

```
cp: keys.local: No such file or directory
```

Can someone explain to an absolute noob how you create a .json on mac?

Comment: Those are just file names. You can create a file using “touch hello.whatever”.

Comment: _"Guessed that was a terminal command?"_ you guessed correctly ~ https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html.

Comment: Where did you save the `keys.local` file? You would need to run the terminal command in the same directory

Comment: @Phil saved it on desktop, tried this code but it just created another .RTF and not a .json

`(base) PhilippsMacBook:~ philippevo$ cd desktop
(base) PhilippsMacBook:desktop philippevo$ cp keys.local.rtf keys.json`

Comment: Try listing the directory contents ~ `ls -la`. Perhaps TextEdit saved it as `keys.local.txt`. Some text editors are stupid like that

Comment: You are correct! Just couldn't get it to convert to .json; sorry do I have to download json or something?

Comment: `mv keys.local.txt keys.local` will rename your file. I suggest you get a better text editor like Visual Studio Code